# Is it possible to keep your companion from attacking right away?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I try to sneak and rain death from above with some arrows to tough enemies like giants, I constantly have my companion running off with her sword and trying to wack at them then almost getting killed.

Is there a way (without interracting with her each time and saying "wait here") that I can have her stay next to me, like Fallout 3+ companion control?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are in sneak mode, your companion will try to sneak too. This means that they won't go charging at the first enemy they see, as long as they remain undetected from that enemy.

Get a high enough stealth skill betwixt the two of you, and she'll stay by your side while you 1-shot monsters with expert sneak shots.

Comment: +1, also it helps a LOT if you give your companion some sort of muffling enchantment, I'm able to sneak up behind enemies and backstab them to death without my companion being detected.

Answer (score 4):

Give her a bow and arrows. She'll shoot with you. You can also take away her weapon and she'll just use the bow.

Comment: meh, tried that, shes got a bow and arrows, she just charges in with her stronger two-hander...

Comment: @Jakub — Typically, followers use whichever weapon deals the most damage.  If you take away any melee weapons you've given her and she still uses her default weapon over the bow, try to find a stronger bow for her.

Comment: I can confirm that works. Jenassa works well for me. She keeps using her Orcish bow even at close range. It's great when playing a melee oriented character.